# How to get refs from another component in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The code in main App component is as follows :

```
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
      console.log(this.ref);
      debugger;
  }

  render() {

    return (
        <div>
            <Header/>
            {this.props.children}
            <Footer/>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And one of the components which renders with `{this.props.children}` is HomePage, where are sections with refs.

The code of a HomePage is as follows :

```
render(){
     return (
        <div className="homeMain">
            <section ref="info"> <Info/> </section>

            <section ref="contact"> <Contact /> </section>
       </div>
    );
}
```

How can I get those refs inside App component to be able to pass them as props to header?

I'm trying to do it inside componentDidMount in App component, but `console.log(this.refs)` is empty.

Any advice?

**EDIT**

The whole App component :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Footer from './common/footer';
import Header from './common/header';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from './components/homepage/login/authActions';

class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        console.log(this.props.children.refs);
        debugger;

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header route={this.props.location.pathname}
                        language={this.props.language.labels}
                        authenticated={this.props.authenticated}
                        signoutAction={this.props.actions}
                        offsets={this.props.offsets}
                />
                {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
                    currentLanguage: this.props.language.labels,
                    authenticated: this.props.authenticated
                })}
                <div className="clearfix"/>
                <Footer currentLanguage={this.props.language.labels}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        language: state.language,
        authenticated: state.auth.authenticated,
        offsets: state.offsets
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: `this.refs` will show all the refs of **current** component and you have not defined any refs there.

Comment: But they are defined in one of the child components. How can I get them?

Comment: @Boky you mean pass refs from child to parent via props? upward?

Comment: You can't and you should not. Can you tell us what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @MyMasterPeice Yes. Something like that.

Comment: If I understand right, you have to do some changes on certain event. And you are trying to pass refs to parent so you can manipulate. Rather, you should pass function reference as props and call it on that event

Comment: @Rajesh I have an scroll animation to one of those sections when user clicks on a link in nav bar (which is in header). Those sections are in HomePage component. But I want to be able to navigate if i'm on a registration page. Now, if I'm on a registration page, if I click on one of those links, nothing happens beacause those refs are empty.

Comment: If you want to do something like this i think that you should define a method on children component and call the method from parent via refs, another way could be the implementation of a event emitter

Comment: Have you found your solution yet, I have just up-voted your question, and also posted an answer below

Answer (score 10):

The React's main idea is passing props downward from parent to children (even to deeper levels of children - grandchildren I mean)

Therefore, when we want the parent to do something which is triggered from (or belongs to) the children, we can create a callback function  in the parent, then pass it down to children as props

For your preference, this is a demonstration on how to pass callback functions downward through many levels of children and how to trigger them:

[Force React container to refresh data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43589766/force-react-container-to-refresh-data/43602934#43602934)

[Re-initializing class on redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43601156/re-initializing-class-on-redirect/43602364#43602364)

In your case, you can access refs from children components as follows: (using string for ref - as you stated)

**Parent Component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import Child component here

export default class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    // ...
    this.getRefsFromChild = this.getRefsFromChild.bind(this);
  }    

  getRefsFromChild(childRefs) {
    // you can get your requested value here, you can either use state/props/ or whatever you like based on your need case by case
    this.setState({
      myRequestedRefs: childRefs
    });
    console.log(this.state.myRequestedRefs); // this should have *info*, *contact* as keys
  }    

  render() {
    return (
      <Child passRefUpward={this.getRefsFromChild} />
    )
  }  
}
```

**Child Component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Child extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    // ...
  }    

  componentDidMount() {
    // pass the requested ref here
    this.props.passRefUpward(this.refs);

  }    

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="homeMain">
        <section ref="info"> <Info/> </section>

        <section ref="contact"> <Contact /> </section>
      </div>          
    )
  }  
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm and saved me hours of re-works for a simple feature

Answer (score 0):

`ref` is property of each `this.props.children` hence you can access ref of child component in parent via `ref` property on `this.props.children`

Make sure you access ref after `componentDidMount`

Edit :

Try below set of code if this works :

```
var myChild= React.Children.only(this.props.children);
var clone = React.cloneElement(myChild, { ref: "myRef" });
```

Comment: `componentDidMount(){ console.log(this.props.children.ref) }` returns null.

Comment: make sure this.props.children exists

Comment: It exists, the content of the HomePage is rendered.

Comment: The same problem.

Comment: can u post complete code , how are you accessing ref

Comment: there is no s in word 'ref' -> ` console.log(this.props.children.refs);` , please remove s from 'refs' above statment and do console.log

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125885/discussion-between-boky-and-mymasterpeice).