# Force React container to refresh data

Tags: reactjs

In my React application, I have two distinct types of components: *presentations* and *containers*. It's roughly after Dan Abromov's ["Presentational and Container Components"](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0), except I don't use Flux or Redux.

Now, I have the following structure:

```
UsersContainer
├── UsersListContainer
|   └── UsersListView
└── AddUserContainer
```

The `UsersListContainer` is responsible for loading data from some REST API, and if that succeeds, it delegates presenting that data to the `UsersListView`.

The `AddUserContainer` is responsible for adding a new user, again, by invoking an REST API. Now, when that was successful, I would like the `UsersListContainer` to refresh its data.

The best I can think of is this:

```
class AddUserContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // Other UI elements omitted for brevity
    return (<button onClick={ e => props.onUserAdded() }>Add user</button>);
  }
}

class UsersListContainer extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    // start fetching data using window.fetch;
    // the promise callback will but retrieved data into this.state
  }
  render() {
    return (<table></table>);
  }
}

class UsersContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const forceUpdate = this.setState({ ...this.state, refreshToken: Math.random() });
    // Other UI elements omitted for brevity
    <UsersListContainer key={ this.state.refreshToken } />
    <AddUserContainer onUserAdded={ forceUpdate } />
  }
}
```

But this approach feels like mis-using the `key` prop. Is there a better / more elegant way to do this?

Comment: This is exactly why state should be shared by the parent component which is what flex/redux do.

Comment: In short, make `UsersContainer` to trigger the fetch of users and let `UsersContainer` to keep users in its internal state. Then just pass it down to `UsersListContainer ` as props. That will ensure `UsersListContainer` will rerender correctly when users change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use Flux or Redux yet, then updating peer-components (in your case, UsersListContainer and AddUserContainer) is a bit, in my opinion, anti-pattern for React.

The main idea of React is, to me, passing props from parent to children, therefore, Irvin Lim's idea to "got rid of UsersListContainer but moved AddUserContainer into UsersContainer" will make it easier for you to control when to update your component!

Your current approaching and my idea are the same: in your **UsersContainer**, create a method to forceUpdate it, then pass it along to **AddUserContainer**, and after this AddUserContainer added a user, you trigger that updating method on the parent:

```
<AddUserContainer onUserAdded={ this.props.updatingParent } />
```

For your reference, or for anyone else who wants to understand about how to update the parent component whenever child (or grandchild or great-grandchild) updates, please refer to my answer to another similar issue:

[Re-initializing class on redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43601156/re-initializing-class-on-redirect/43602364#43602364)

If you still keep your current component-hierarchy, when **UsersContainer** is updated, its child-components (*UsersListContainer* and *AddUserContainer*) will be updated, too. However, *AddUserContainer* will once again be updated!

As a result, I still think in your case, using Flux or Redux is a nice approaching, which eliminates to complexity of passing props through many levels of deep & complicated component-hierarchy

Answer (score 4):

Check out [react-refetch](https://github.com/heroku/react-refetch), which provides a nice API for `fetch`ing, and allows you to implement the Presentational and Container Components pattern, without using Flux/Redux for API calls.

It also lets you handle loading and errored states, which is definitely necessary for a decent web application today.

In the example below, I got rid of `UsersListContainer` but moved `AddUserContainer` into `UsersContainer` as well. This makes your `UsersListView` the presentational component for `UsersContainer`. Feel free to change the naming as you wish. This is so that I can get the `refreshUsers` prop to pass into `AddUserContainer`.

```reactjs
// UsersContainer.js

const Container = ({ usersFetch, refreshUsers }) => {
    if (userFetch.pending) {
        return <LoadingDisplay />
    } else if (usersFetch.rejected) {
        return <ErrorDisplay error={ usersFetch.reason } />
    } else if (usersFetch.fulfilled) {
        return (
            <UsersListView users={ usersFetch.value } />
            <AddUserContainer handleAddUser={ refreshUsers } />
        );
    }
};

const refetch = (props) => {
    const usersFetch = `/api/users`;

    return {
        usersFetch: usersFetch,
        refreshUsers: () => ({
            usersFetch: { ...usersFetch, force: true, refreshing: true }
        }),
    };
};

export default connect(refetch)(Container);
```

Check out the documentation for more examples. I personally prefer to use react-refetch for API-heavy applications, rather than implementing the calls in Redux.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It gave me some nice ideas about employing higher-order components for showing loading animations and the like.