# React JS - trigger event on certain state value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I trigger an event from a parent component when its child component's state holds a certain value?

For example: say I have a Parent component and a Child component, where the parent's state has the property activeIndex and the child's state has the property activeTask.

I want to trigger the parent's props.handleNextChild method if the child's state's activeTask property equals 3.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've changed the logic of my app:
just set active child index in my json-data and use it as state

```
@Statements = React.createClass
  displayName: 'Statements'
  getInitialState: ->
    statements: @props.statements
    attempt: @props.attempt
    activeIndex: @props.attempt.active_statement

  updateStates: (data) ->
    @setState activeIndex: data.attempt.active_statement
    @setState attempt: data.attempt
    @setState statements: data.statements
```

Answer (score 3):

Whenever the state or props of your component change, the lifecycle method `componentDidUpdate` gets called after the update is done, so you could pass `handleNextChild` as a prop to your child:

```js
class Parent extends Component {
    handleNextChild() {
      //do whatever
    }

    render() {
      return (
        //stuff
        <Child callback={() => handleNextChild()} /> //arrow for lexical bind
        //more stuff
      );
    }
 }
```

and change your child component class:

```js
class Child extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.callbackHandled = false
  }

  // ...child class code...

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.activeTask === 3) {
    this.callbackHandled = false;
    this.setState({ activeTask: resetValue }, () => {
      if (!this.callbackHandled) {
        this.callbackHandled = true;
        this.props.callback();
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    // render your child component...
  }
}
```

This will get triggered whenever your state's `activeTask` property changes to 3. However, as long as `activeTask` stays at 3, it will run on every update, so if you want it to run only once, be sure to `setState` to reset `activeTask` before you call `callback` as I have done. I have used the callback version of `setState` and an nstance variable in order to ensure the state gets set *before* the callback (aka: `handleNextChild`) is called in order to avoid calling it multiple times, and to ensure that the child gets handled exactly once each time `activeTask` is set to 3.

Comment: if we need to fire `handleNextChild` only once, we can add another state props called something like `currentChildHandled` and set it `true` if we met  requierments, and add to requierments so it must be `false`

Comment: Indeed. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: That wouldn't work as state, though (because you never know if a state change might get preempted) and it isn't a good fit for state anyway (because rendering does not depend on it ) so I added it as an instance variable instead.

Comment: I've just upvoted your answer back ^^, which is the same as my idea. Passing callback from parent and using componentDidUpdate is the correct way, in my opinion. I have also answered several ones related to passing callback as props and when to trigger it from child-component: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43589766/force-react-container-to-refresh-data/43602934#43602934 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43601156/re-initializing-class-on-redirect/43602364#43602364

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight way to achieve this, create a call back in parent and pass it down to child via props.Then keep checking in the child if the desired condition is met and then trigger the callback.

pseudo code:

**Parent**

```
class Parent extends Component {
    handleNextChild = () => {
            // parent logic comes here
    }
    render() {
        return (
                <Child handleNextChild = this.handleNextChild />
        );
    }
}
```

**Child:**

```
class Child extends Component {
    onChange = () => {
            if(this.state.activeTask === 3){ 
                this.props.handleNextChild();
            }
    }.....
```

Comment: `onChange` is not available on all components. In addition, just doing `handleNextChild` without resetting state might result in multiple spurious calls.

Comment: @PedroCastilho where does op say he doesn't need multiple calls, and also onChange is not available in any component unless you add it is a callback. So just don't make any assumptions and give the idea to solve the problem to op. It's just a pseudo code.

Comment: The problem is that you need a lifecycle method here to check if the desired condition is met, so even if you pass `onChange` as a callback, this does not work. And the way OP's question is worded implies that they want to trigger the event once per state change.

Comment: By the way, I would appreciate it if you could provide some constructive criticism on why you downvoted my answer.

Comment: I've just upvoted you guys' answers back ^^, which is helpful anyway, and similar to my idea, which is passing callback from parent. However, I think here that we should use use componentDidUpdate as of @pedro-castilho 's answer. I have also answered several ones related to passing callback as props and when to trigger it from child-component: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43589766/force-react-container-to-refresh-data/43602934#43602934 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43601156/re-initializing-class-on-redirect/43602364#43602364