# Access to internal function from externally loaded HTML in React component

Tags: reactjs

I have the following use case.

Some HTML from a third party source is loaded inside my React component:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.externalHTML }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Inside the externally loaded HTML a click event exists for a specific span, which is supposed to call a callback function that exists in my application.

```
<span onclick="myCallback(param1='asd', param2=123, param3='asdas')">
  Click me!
</span>
```

Where should I put this *myCallback* function?

If I place it inside the component class I get the following error when clicking the span, because as I understand the function is not visible to the externally loaded HTML: **Uncaught ReferenceError: myCallback is not defined at HTMLSpanElement.onclick**

My other idea was to add the function to the window object `window.myCallback = ...` inside my main index.js file to be loaded every time the app loads. This way it works but I have two issues.

- My understanding is that this is not the correct React way to do it.
- Whenever I click the span element the callback function is triggered twice and I cannot understand why.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" is ..."dangerous" as its name ^^, which is actually not pure React way, either.

However, If you have to do it, you can do something like this (take advantage of built-in jQuery inside React be default)

=====

EDITED VERSION FROM HERE: (use only 1 component)

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // using jQuery to manipulate DOM element form third-party source
    // NB. you may think of using setTimeout here, to wait for the external source to be fully loaded here, of course it's not so safe
    // but anyway, we are using "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" anyway => quite dangerous, though ^^  

    // setTimeout(function(){   
      $(document.findElementsByTagName("span")[0]).click(function(e){ 
      // or perhaps $("#spanID").click if you can, just be careful between DOM element and react component

          e.preventDefault();
          // DO SOMETHING HERE, just like you do in the window.onload function
          // or maybe you also need to get param values by getting $(this).data("...") or $(this).attr("ATTRIBUTE-NAME")
          return false;

      });
    // });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.externalHTML }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

=====

OLD ANSWER FROM HERE: (use 2 components)

**ParentComponent:**

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.callbackOnThisComponent = this.callbackOnThisComponent.bind(this);
  }
  callbackOnThisComponent(param1, param2, param3) {
    // do whatever you like with the above params
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ChildComponent triggerCallbackOnParent={this.callbackOnThisComponent} />
    );
  }
}
```

**ChildComponent:**

```
export default class ChildComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // using jQuery to manipulate DOM element form third-party source

    let that = this;

    // NB. you may think of using setTimeout here, to wait for the external source to be fully loaded here, of course it's not so safe
    // but anyway, we are using "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" anyway => quite dangerous, though ^^  

    $(document.findElementsByTagName("span")[0]).click(function(e){ 
    // or perhaps $("#spanID").click if you can, just be careful between DOM element and react component

        e.preventDefault();
        that.props.triggerCallbackOnParent(param1, param2, param3);
        // or maybe you need to get param values by getting $(this).data("...") or $(this).attr("ATTRIBUTE-NAME")
        return false;

    }, that);

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.externalHTML }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

I just use the main React's idea, which is passing props downward to children components, and when you want to trigger a function upward from child component, create a callback function on parent. For your or anyone else's reference, this is my demonstration on how to pass callback function from parent to multi-level-children components:

[Force React container to refresh data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43589766/force-react-container-to-refresh-data/43602934#43602934)

[Re-initializing class on redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43601156/re-initializing-class-on-redirect/43602364#43602364)

if this doesn't work yet, feel free to show me some error logs, thanks

Comment: I don't have another way to do this than using dangerouslySetInnerHTML. I know that it is dangerous. :) But I do not want to use jquery either. Is this the only way?

Comment: Actually, third-party source is just HTML, not react-component, and may not have event bound to it yet, unless we use javascript to bind the events later. Therefore, if you don't wanna use jQuery, you may use "pure" javascript, I think: something like "document.getElementById("spanID").addEventListener("click", function(){})" ^^