# React - how can I trigger action from inline html?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an app that takes markdown and renders it as html. My goal is to implement checkboxes - user types "[ ]" into markdown, after markdown is rendered, I replace "[ ]" with a checkbox, and when the user clicks on this rendered checkbox, I want to replace "[ ]" with "[X]" in the source markdown.

So I need to somehow tell react that checkbox has been clicked, but checkbox is not a component, it is just a manually inserted inline html.

Is there any way for me to trigger actions from it?

Or is there any way to somehow replace parts of the html generated from markdown with react components?

Comment: how do you replace [] with checkboxes?

Comment: markdown = markdown.replace(checkboxRegexp,`<span class="checkbox"></span>`);

Answer (score 0):

You will have to convert HTML to Components to make it work.
If your markdown parser only returns HTML then traverse it and create components out of tags.

Answer (score 0):

Your current way of rendering HTML is somewhat not the pure react's way, and then the html is even changed by using javascript `replace` ^^, I mean it's a bit dangerous!

However, if there's some reason you must use the current way, you may read my answer here, which shows the same solution for your case:

[Access to internal function from externally loaded HTML in React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43626996/access-to-internal-function-from-externally-loaded-html-in-react-component/43628058#43628058)

While replacing the texts with checkboxes, you may add more parameters to the checkboxes, then react's built-in jQuery may help you add click-events to the checkboxes!

If my way doesn't work for you yet, please feel free to post here some log errors, we may find a good work-around way together!