# React - How do I pass a state two tiers up, and then down to another child?

Tags: reactjs, state

I have a state from `<Left Child 2/>` that I wish to pass to `<Right Child 2/>`. They both have one parent(the one above), and refer to the same parent container.

The structure is something like this:

```
     <ParentContainer />
        |            |
        |            |
        v            v
<Left Child 1/> <Right Child 1/>
        v            v
<Left Child 2/> <Right Child 2/>
```

How do I pass data not one, but two tiers up in React, and then propagate it down another tree from the same Parent?

Comment: You don't. You keep the shared state in the common parent. You don't keep it in a child and that pass it through the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a function and default internal state in your parent component. Then pass down the function into `<Left Child 2/>` and call the function there which will set the passed data as a state of the parent component, which you can pass down to `<Right Child 1/>` with props.

The key here is to have a **single source of truth** for your data, which should be the parent component.

Comment: I see. In practice, the data is actually fetched(via an Ajax call to a REST api) in the `<ParentContainer />`, and it isn't updated in the left child 2.. but I need it as an input to right child 2, to do another Ajax call based on some unique info in it, if that makes sense(likely doesn't). But thanks i'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

My answers to other similar questions will work in your case, too. The main idea is to pass a callback function from parent downward to multi-level-children components, then when and how to trigger that callback function from the children component.

=====

Feel free to read my answers, which are not so complicated, I think ^^ :

[Force React container to refresh data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43589766/force-react-container-to-refresh-data/43602934#43602934) (this is similar issue)

and

[Re-initializing class on redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43601156/re-initializing-class-on-redirect/43602364#43602364) (this is my main explanation, which is a demonstration on how to pass a callback function as props downward through multi-level-children and how to trigger it)

=====

Actually, when the parent component updates, all its children will be updated, too!
Therefore, as already stated in the above's links, using Flux or Redux in your case will be a nice approaching, which eliminates the complexity of passing props through many levels of children components