# How to link on click function to another component in React app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a landing page that contains a logo. I'm trying to get this logo to trigger a change of of state value. The purpose of this is to change from the landing page to the home page on click. I have set it up so that the landing page clear in an determined time, but I want to do this on click. This is my `splash.js` file that contains the on click function as well as the logo and landing page:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Woods from './woods.jpeg';
import Logo1 from './whitestar.png';


export default class Splash extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
            this.toggleShowHome = this.toggleShowHome.bind(this);
    }

    toggleShowHome(property){
        this.setState((prevState)=>({[property]:!prevState[property]}))
     }

    render() {
        return(
            <div id='Splashwrapper'>
                <img src={Woods}></img>
                <img id='logoc' src={Logo1} onClick={()=>this.toggleShowHome('showSquareOne')}></img>
            </div>    
        );  
    }
}
```

I want the on click function to change the value of `splash` to false in my `App.js` file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Splash from './splash';

import Menu from 'components/Global/Menu';

export default class About extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            splash: true
        }

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout (() => {
        this.setState({splash: false});
        }, 10000);
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.splash) {
            return <Splash />
        }

        const { children } = this.props; // eslint-disable-line

        return (
            <div className='About'>
                <Menu />
                { children }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

How can I link the on click function to the `App.js` file and change the value of `splash`?

Answer (score 0):

To make sure I'm understanding, you're looking for the image on the `Splash` component to trigger a change in the `About` component?

You can pass a method to your Splash component (from About) that it can call when the image is pressed. So something like this:

```
render() {
   if(this.state.splash) {
      return <Splash onLogoClicked={this.logoClicked.bind(this)} />
   }
   (.......)
}
logoClicked(foo) {
   < change state here >
}
```

And then in your Splash component:

```
<img id='logoc' src={Logo1} onClick={this.props.onLogoClicked}></img>
```

Comment: Ah sorry. It should be `onClick={this.props.onLogoClicked}`. I have edited my answer appropriately.

Comment: I can't get it to work for some reason..`logoClicked(foo) {
  this.setState({splash:false})
 }` should change the state on click of the logo right?

Comment: Here is a working, simplified, version of your code. https://jsfiddle.net/2e6wxkwo/

Comment: I keep trying to apply this but it simply does nothing on my end..My `Splash` component is in my `splash.js` file, while `About` is in another file`App.js`. I import `Splash` in my `App.js` file but this just won't work..

Answer (score 0):

You should define your function toggleShowHome in app.is and pass it as a prop to your splash component. Then you could change your local state in app.js

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood you well, but you can try this: to pass the on click function from parent (About) to child (Splash), something like this:

**YOUR MAIN APP:**

```
export default class About extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            splash: true
        }
        this.changeSplashState = this.changeSplashState.bind(this);
    }

    //componentDidMount() {
        //setTimeout (() => {
        //this.setState({splash: false});
        //}, 10000);
    //}

    changeSplashState() {
        this.setState({splash: false});
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.splash) {
            return <Splash triggerClickOnParent={this.changeSplashState} />
        }

        const { children } = this.props; // eslint-disable-line

        return (
            <div className='About'>
                <Menu />
                { children }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**YOUR SPLASH COMPONENT:**

```
export default class Splash extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        //this.toggleShowHome = this.toggleShowHome.bind(this);
    }

    toggleShowHome(property){
        this.setState((prevState)=>({[property]:!prevState[property]}));
        //IT'S UP TO YOU TO DECIDE SETTING TIMOUT OR NOT HERE
        //setTimeout (() => {
            this.props.triggerClickOnParent();
        //}, 10000);
     }

    render() {
        return(
            <div id='Splashwrapper'>
                <img src={Woods}></img>
                <img id='logoc' src={Logo1} onClick={this.toggleShowHome.bind(this,'showSquareOne')}></img>
            </div>    
        );  
    }
}
```

Feel free to post here some errors or explain to me more about what you need, but that is the way it should look like, a standard way to pass function as props from parent to child.

You can also read more about how to pass props from parent to child/grandchild/many-deeper-level-child (of course in react's way):

[Force React container to refresh data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43589766/force-react-container-to-refresh-data/43602934#43602934)

[Re-initializing class on redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43601156/re-initializing-class-on-redirect/43602364#43602364)

Comment: I need to be able to click on `logoc` and change the state of `splash` in `About`..

Comment: showSquareOne doesn't exists anymore in this code, sorry for not fixing this.

Comment: but in fact did you try my code? I think it should work for you? If not, could you please show some errors on the console, thanks. Currently, you can now click on "logo" and it will do something!

Comment: I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`

Comment: the error happens on which line, sorry if I may ask ?

Comment: did you use "<img id='logoc' src={Logo1} onClick={this.toggleShowHome.bind(this,'showSquareOne')}></img>" the syntax for logoc is now different from your last version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145591/discussion-between-feners-and-thinhvo0108).