# React search bar searching text in Div in a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a search bar to search a text in a component, may i know if it is possible to do?

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
       return (
           /**search the text inside this DIV**/
          <div> this is a dog. </div>
       )
    }
}
```

Thanks:)

Comment: you can select all div using document.querySelectorAll and check text inside of div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the way I would implement it

```
class App extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        console.log(e.target.value); // your search bar text
        let object = this.refs.Progress1; // get your div element using refs
        console.log(object.textContent); // your div text

        // now that you have the two strings you can do your search in your favorite way, for example:

        let searchBarText = e.target.value;
        let divText = object.textContent;
        if (divText.includes(searchBarText)) {
            console.log("the div text contains your search text");
        } else {
            console.log("the div text doesn't contain search text");
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" className="input" onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Search..." />
                <div ref="Progress1">
                    this is a dog. ...
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Update:** if the div and the search bar are in two different React components without parent/child relation, I would implement it as follows:

`Class A` having the `div`

```
class A extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div id="myDiv">
                    this is a dog. ...
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

`class B` having the search bar

```
class B extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        console.log(e.target.value); // your search bar text
        let object = document.getElementById("myDiv");
        console.log(object.textContent); // your div text

        // now that you have the two strings you can do your search in your favorite way, for example:

        let searchBarText = e.target.value;
        let divText = object.textContent;
        if (divText.includes(searchBarText)) {
            console.log("the div text contains your search text");
        } else {
            console.log("the div text doesn't contain search text");
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" className="input" onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Search..." />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

If there is a parent/child relation between the two classes/components you should rely on props passing between parent and child, see this question for an example: [How to get refs from another component in React JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40080742/how-to-get-refs-from-another-component-in-react-js)

Comment: Thank you for your help, sorry for not making my query clear, it should be for example, class A has the search function, and class B has a div,  the class A search function can search the text in div in Class B, is it possible to do this?

Comment: thank you so much Mis94^_^, it works now, but when i try to highlight the word that is found in DIV , it does find the word, but it removes the some words at the same time, for example, when i search "a", it highlights "a" but it also removes the words "this is".i have attached my code in my post. is it possible to fix it?

Comment: @feng li if you see my answer solves your main question of this post please accept my answer. Concerning your new question, It would be better to post it as a new question and not discuss it here in order to get better help.

Answer (score 0):

Is the text inside of your component pure markup or controlled within the component's state?

If it's pure markup then you'll have to interact with the dom -- something you can do using refs:

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

In either case, whether it's controlled component or markup, you'll have to obtain that inner text somehow and pass it to an event handler attached to your search bar. From there the question is the best way to search within text. I'll leave that up to you (Regex, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone searching how to do it in React Hook. This is for you:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [isFound, setFound] = useState(false);
  const paragraphEl = useRef(null);

  const handleInput = (e) => {
    setText(e.target.value);
    const paragraphText = paragraphEl.current.textContent;
    if (e.target.value !== "" && paragraphText.includes(e.target.value)) {
      setFound(true);
    } else {
      setFound(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Search text</h1>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Type here"
        value={text}
        onChange={handleInput}
      />
      <p ref={paragraphEl}>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
        veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
        commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
        velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
        occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
        mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
      {isFound && <p style={{ color: "green" }}>We found it</p>}
    </div>
  );
}
```